# How to start celery task after django request finished

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I need to run celery task only when django request  finished.
Is it possible?

Comment: For all requests or a specific view?

Comment: For all request, because I write transaction important service. So I need that all tasks starts after request finish.

Comment: Try to start the task in a middleware?

Comment: You could look at using the `request_finished` signal. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#module-django.core.signals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

Django sends request_finished at the end of every request.
You can access request object through sender argument,

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.signals import request_finished

from app.tasks import my_task

@receiver(request_finished)
def add_celery_task(sender):
    if sender.__name__ != 'StaticFilesHandler':
        my_task.delay()
```

If you are running server in development environment it's good to check sender's name to avoid adding too many celery task for every static file you are serving.

Comment: if u add breakpoint in  requset_finished receiver call back still stop the responses

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the best way to make sure your task happens after the request is finished is to write a custom middleware. In the `process_response` method, you can handle any quick actions that don't impact page load time or performance too much. Anything else, you can hand off to Celery. Any saving or database transactions are completed by the time `process_response` is called (AFAICT).

Answer (score -2):

You can run the task in the background, using delay method of celery. I mean just before returning the response you can call the delay method to put the task in the background.

Some thing like this:

```
task_name.delay(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

By doing this your task will be put into background and run asynchronously, this is not going to block the request response cycle .

Comment: What can happen, however, is the task gets executed before the transaction is committed. If you've added something to a database table that the task is expected to operate on, it can fail even with .delay(...). I believe the original question is how to avoid this.